# mjpeg_sever cmake error:Unknown CMake command "catkin_project"

Tags: ros, mjpeg-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the http://www.ros.org/wiki/mjpeg_server

and svn co http://svn.code.sf.net/p/bosch-ros-pkg/code/trunk/stacks/remote_lab/mjpeg_server

But when I cmake it. there's error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (catkin_project):
> Unknown CMake command "catkin_project".

How to deal with it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40028/mjpeg_sever-cmake-error:unknown-cmake-command-%22catkin_project%22./) by [koprenee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2889/koprenee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-27**:
Which version of ROS are you on? Fuerte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Koprenee,

since the day you asked the question we switched back to rosmake from catkin. I don't know if you already tried, but if you check out the latest code and do

rosmake mjpeg_server

it should compile just fine.

Ben

---

Originally posted by [bener suay](https://answers.ros.org/users/1003/bener-suay/) with karma: 178 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1